# Power Query. Merge duplicated lines in a row with collapsing values

Tags: excel, merge, duplicates, concatenation, powerquery

I have a bus schedule with Stops, Time_in and Time_out. Sometimes in my data Stops are duplicated (in a row) and I need to merge them, leaving only first Time_in and last Time_out.

So here's an example:

| Stop | Time_in | Time_out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23rd Street | 15:23 | 15:27 |
| **42nd Street** | **15:35** | 15:40 |
| **42nd Street** | 15:42 | **15:48** |
| 47th Street | 15:56 | 16:10 |
| 42nd Street | 16:14 | 16:19 |

Wanted result:

| Stop | Time_in | Time_out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23rd Street | 15:23 | 15:27 |
| **42nd Street** | **15:35** | **15:48** |
| 47th Street | 15:56 | 16:10 |
| 42nd Street | 16:14 | 16:19 |

Would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery, right click column Stop, and Group By....

Choose Add grouping

For the first row pick operation min on column Time_in

For the second row pick the operation max on column Time_out

If needed, change type number to type time in the formula bar or in home ... advanced editor..

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Stop", type text}, {"Time_in", type time}, {"Time_out", type time}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Stop"}, {{"Time_in", each List.Min([Time_in]), type time}, {"Time_out", each List.Max([Time_out]), type time}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

For new requirement that Stops can repeat, we first create a group number that makes sure the Stops are in adjacent rows before combining them

Add column index column

Add column, custom column with formula

```
= try if #"Added Index"{[Index]}[Stop] = #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Stop] then null else [Index] otherwise [Index]
```

right click new column and fill down

Click both the Stop and Custom column and group on that

Choose Add aggregation

For the first row pick operation min on column Time_in

For the second row pick the operation max on column Time_out.

Sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Stop", type text}, {"Time_in", type time}, {"Time_out", type time}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try if #"Added Index"{[Index]}[Stop] = #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Stop] then null else [Index] otherwise [Index]),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Stop", "Custom"}, {{"Time_in", each List.Min([Time_in]), type time}, {"Time_out", each List.Max([Time_out]), type time}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Hello horseyride, thank you very much! Could you suggest a solution where values in the Stop column could be repeated (so we can't use group by, otherwise further stops will disappear). I need to remove values from Stops which are repeated in a row only. The bus can visit the same stops, and I don't want to lose them

Answer (score 0):

Power Query

```
    let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194967/power-query-merge-duplicated-rows-with-collapsing-values"),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(3) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, {"Column2", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(3) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}, {"Column3", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(3) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(3)"}}, [RowSelector="DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(3) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR"]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Extracted Table From Html", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Stop", type text}, {"Time_in", type time}, {"Time_out", type time}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Time_out"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Stop"}, {{"ad_1", each _, type table [Stop=nullable text, Time_in=nullable time]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each let x= [ad_1],
 #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(x,{"Stop"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Time_in", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each ([Index] = 1)),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"ad_1"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom", {"Time_in"}, {"Time_in"}),
    Custom1 = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Time_in"}),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(Custom1, {"Stop"}, {{"ad_2", each _, type table [Stop=nullable text, Time_out=nullable time]}}),
    Custom2 = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows1", "Custom", each let x= [ad_2],
 #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(x,{"Stop"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Time_out", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each ([Index] = 1)),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(Custom2,{"ad_2"}),
    #"Expanded Custom1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "Custom", {"Time_out"}, {"Time_out"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Custom", {"Stop"}, #"Expanded Custom1", {"Stop"}, "Expanded Custom1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Expanded Custom1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Expanded Custom1", {"Time_out"}, {"Time_out"})
in
    #"Expanded Expanded Custom1"
```

DAX

```
min:= MIN('Table 1'[Time_in])
max:= MAX('Table 1'[Time_out])
```

DAX result

[image: dax_result]

Comment: Hello smpa01, thank you very much! I tried your solution and realized that I miss al of the repeated stops, but I need to remove values from Stops which are repeated in a row only. The bus can visit the same stops, and I don't want to lose them all, just need to collapse some of them. Sorry for not immediately clarifying this point